# Speed up linq query perfomance

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm running this linq query which is a little big.

```
var events = _context.Event.OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate).Where(e => e.IsPresentation == true).Where(e => e.IsCanceled == false).Where(e => e.StartDate > new DateTime());
```

And the page outputing the data from this query is taking too much time to load. Maybe because I'm using too many wheres.

I had the same issue using includes, and then includes, in a different query, but I divided the query, to improve the performance. But I'm trying to figure it out how to do the same thing in that situation, because I'm not using any include.

Comment: try to use one ``where`` but before Ordering ; ``DateTime now = DataTime.Now;
var events = _context.Event
 .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled && e.StartDate > now)
 .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate)``

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS and include the table design, including indexes, and an estimate of the total number of rows, and the number that satisfy each of your .Where predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the performance of the query will largely depend on the table size, and availability of suitable indices.

A couple things I can note from that query:

This statement doesn't make a lot of sense: `.Where(e => e.StartDate > new DateTime())`. `new DateTime()` will initialize a DateTime from 01/01/0001. Any dates stored in an SQL Server DateTime column for example will be from 01/01/1753, so this seems rather moot. If the database/entity DateTime value is null-able, then `.Where(e => e.StartDate.HasValue)` would be more applicable. If the DateTime value is not null-able then this condition can be left off entirely.

So if the field is null-able, the Linq expression would look more like:

```
var events = _context.Event
    .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled && e.StartDate.HasValue)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate)
    .ToList();
```

If it's not null-able:

```
var events = _context.Event
    .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate)
    .ToList();
```

The next culprit to eliminate: Lazy Load proxy hits. Does the Event property have navigation properties to any other entities?  If this is something like a web application and you are serializing entities to send back to the client, navigation property EF proxies can absolutely kill performance. Any code after this call that touches a navigation property will result in extra individual DB calls to lazy load these navigation properties. For methods that return lists of entities this can be critical. If an Event has a reference to something like a User and you load 1000 events referencing roughly 1000 users, when a serializer goes to serialize those 1000 events, it will "touch" each of the user references. This leads to ~1000 extra SQL statements effectively doing `SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserId = 1`, `SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserId = 2`... etc. etc. for each User ID in each Event.  If you need these related entities you can Eager load them with `Include(e => e.User)` which will be faster than loading them individually, but this does mean loading a lot of extra data into memory that your client/code may not need. You can avoid the lazy load hits by turning off lazy loading & proxies, but this will leave these entities with #null references which means any code expecting an Event entity with any related details may get one of these partially loaded entities. (not good, the entity should always be in a complete or complete-able state) The final option is to use `Select` to populate a view model for your results. This can speed up queries considerably because you can have EF compose a query to pull back just the data you need from whatever entities rather than everything or triggering lazy loads.

For example if you just need an EventId, EventNumber, Name, StartDate, and a UserName to display for the events:

```
var events = _context.Event
    .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled && e.StartDate.HasValue)
    .Select(e => new EventViewModel
    {
        EventId = e.EventId,
        EventNumber = e.EventNumber,
        Name = e.Name,
        StartDate = e.StartDate,
        UserName = e.User.Name
    })
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate)
    .ToList();
```

This avoids any lazy load hits and reduces the query run to just the columns needed which can speed up queries significantly.

Next would be to look at the queries EF is running and their relevant execution plan. This can highlight missing/poor indexes, and any unexpected lazy load hits. The method for doing this would depend on your database, but involves running a Profiler against the DB to capture the SQL statements being run while you debug.  From here you can capture the SQL statements that EF generates then run those manually against your database with any DB-side analysis tools. (such as SSMS with SQL Server to get an execution plan which can identify missing indexes) Serializer lazy load hits in a web application are detectable as a lot of extra SQL statements executing after your method appears to have completed, but before the data gets back to the client. This is the serializer "touching" proxies resulting in lots of additional queries that the server has to wait to complete before the data is returned to the client.

Lastly would be data volume. Any system that is expected to grow over time should consider the amount of data that can eventually be returned. Anything that returns lists of data over time should incorporate server-side pagination where the client sends a page size and page # where the server can translate this into a `.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize)` operation. (/w page # starting at 0) Most data grid and like components should support server-side pagination to send these arguments to their data load methods.  These controls will need to know the total row count to set up pagination so you would need a method to return that count:

```
var rowCount = _context.Event
    .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled && e.StartDate.HasValue)
    .Count();
```

Same conditions, no order by, and a `.Count()` with no `ToList()` etc. will compose an efficient Count query.

This should give you a few things to check and tweak to eliminate your performance pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

one thing can be sorting at the end because there would be less items and then less time to sort,

***BUT it really depends on your data distribution***. Look if MOST of your data has  e.IsPresentation == true, then the first "Where" does not reduce the data size for you, SO then you are again checking  e.IsCanceled == false on e.g. 95 % your data. But assume only 10 % of your whole data is  e.IsCanceled == false. So now if you apply  e.IsPresentation == true , on that 10% in the second order, it takes much less time than before. So in big databases DB managers usually use different query plans! however the final result is the same. the process time is NOT same. hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should store the value to one variable like `var now = new DateTime()`
2. Combine all of the conditions into one `Where` clause
3. Just `OrderByDescending` after `Where` clause, It means We just order based on actual data instead of all.

```
var now = new DateTime();
var events = _context.Event
                         .Where(e => e.IsPresentation && !e.IsCanceled && e.StartDate > now)
                         .OrderByDescending(e => e.StartDate);
```

**Tips**

You should re-arrange your condition based on actual data. For example:

```
.Where(e => 1 == 2 && 2 == 2 && 3 == 3)
```

As you can see, We no need to manipulate the rest of conditions from `&& 2 == 2 && 3 == 3` because of `and` condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Rúben Dias